# Variance and standard deviation for random distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm using a continuous-uniform-distribution random number generator (in R) to place random numbers in ten equal intervals from 0-1.

I need to calculate the expected value (the expected share of random numbers that fall into each interval) as well as the variance and the standard deviation for that share.

How does one calculate this?

My thinking was that I should think of it as a discrete uniform distribution, given the discrete number of intervals, and use the formula $V(X_1)=(b-a+2)(b-a)/12$, which gives D(X_1)=2.87. I divide this number by 100 to get 0.026, but this seems a wildly large number.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  How many numbers are you placing in $[0,1]$?  If you place $n$ numbers, how are you counting the frequencies of numbers in each interval?  For example, for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 10$, are you interested in how many of the $n$ numbers are in the interval $[(i-1)/10, i/10)$?  This would give you ten integers, say $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{10}$ whose sum equals $n$.  Are you asking about the joint expectation and variance of these?

Answer (score 1):

So you have 10 "shares" $S_i,\; i \in \{1,...,10\}$, where $E[S_i]=\frac{1}{10}$, where $S_i$ is the fraction of draws that will fall in range $i$.

In this case, $Z_i:=nS_i$ follows a multinomial distribution, where $n$ is the number of observations/draws.

In that case,

$$V[Z_i] = np_i(1-p_i) = n\frac{1}{10}\left(1-\frac{1}{10}\right)=\frac{9n}{100}$$

Since $S_i = \frac{Z_i}{n}$ we have:

$$V[S_i]=V\left[\frac1n Z_i\right] = \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{9n}{100}= \frac{9}{100n}$$